# RegEx for matching email in URLs

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls, regex-group

I have a regex in my django code but I don't know what it means actually. Here is my regex :

```
r'^email/(?P<email>[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)/$',
```

Could you give me some examples which match with this regex?

Comment: When I find cryptic regex in the wild I have found https://regex101.com/ a very useful resource to tinker with reverse engineering.

Comment: Yes actually I already tried and actually I tried myurl/email/blabla@blabla.com but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

You can also test/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/j1SUjp/1).

Basically, your expression would match:

```
email/some_alphanumeric[A-Z0-9]_special_chars_@#$*some_alphanumeric_special_chars_#$*.some_alphanumeric_special_chars_#$*
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNye0B/1)

---

If you wish to match:

```
myurl/email/blabla@blabla.com
```

You can [modify it to](https://regex101.com/r/jxUlhG/1):

```
myurl\/email\/([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"myurl\/email\/([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)"

test_str = "myurl/email/blabla@blabla.com"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Actually I tried myurl/email/blabla@blabla.com but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

in addition :

```
r'^email/(?P<email>[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+)/$'
```

this regx use in django url

url example : email/test@gmail.com/

```
email/ = consolent value in your url 

[^@\s] = you can write any character except @ and space "/s"
@[^@\s] = you must start with @ + anything expect @character and space "/s"
\. = matches "."
[^@\s] = you can write anycharacter except @ and space "/s"
+ = you can type many character

/$ = end of url
```